# Requirejs urlArgs paramater in the requirejs-config.js file redirects all the min.js file requests to full .js file urls

Tags: magento2, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I have enabled the production mode in my Magento 2.2.4 version, disabled the static sign functionality and added the parameter: `urlArgs:"version='test'"` in `requirejs-config.js` file. I have enabled the minify js functionality from the backend of Magento 2 . If i do not add this parameter all the dependency are loaded without any issues with the **.min.js** suffix, but once i added that parameter for cache busting functionality, all the dependency are loading with .js suffix and ignoring the **.min.js** files. I am unable to find the solution for this, can anyone please suggest me a solution for it?

Comment: Not getting your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution to this issue. I will say it is not a perfect solution, the below solution has solved my issue, so i am posting it here so that it can help others facing this issue.

**Cause of the problem:**
The problem was that after enabling the production mode in my Magento 2 instance, disabling static version sign and enabling the js minification  from backend `requirejs` was not loading the few `.js` files as `min.js`. So after long hours of debugging i found out that `requirejs-min-resolver.min.js` was the culprit. It was not loading few `min.js` files, the problem is with this line of code where the regular expression: `url=url.replace(/(\.min)?\.js$/,'.min.js');` was not loading few `.js` files as `min.js`.

**The fix:**
`requirejs-min-resolver.min.js` file is created from this php class, override this below method using `di.xml`:

```
vendor/magento/framework/RequireJs/Config.php

public function getMinResolverCode()
    {
        $excludes = [];
        foreach ($this->minification->getExcludes('js') as $expression) {
            $excludes[] = '!url.match(/' . str_replace('/', '\/', $expression) . '/)';
        }
        $excludesCode = empty($excludes) ? 'true' : implode('&&', $excludes);

        $result = <<<code
    var ctx = require.s.contexts._,
        origNameToUrl = ctx.nameToUrl;

    ctx.nameToUrl = function() {
        var url = origNameToUrl.apply(ctx, arguments);
        if ({$excludesCode}) {
            //url = url.replace(/(\.min)?\.js$/, '.min.js'); // commented this line of code.
           //added below line of code 
        if( (url.match('static/frontend/Vendor') || url.match('static/adminhtml/Magento')) && !url.match('.min.js') && !url.match('.json')){url=url.replace('.js','.min.js');} 
        }
        return url;
    };

code;

        if ($this->minification->isEnabled('js')) {
            $result = $this->minifyAdapter->minify($result);
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

**Note:** The expression that i have used has full filled my requirment, please change that according to your own requirement.

**Solution impact area:**
The above expression will blindly start adding the `.min.js` extension to all the `.js` files that are loaded from our Magento 2 instance. Please take care that it does not start adding the `.min.js` extension to third party `.js` files even though i have taken care of it in the above custom  expression.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was enough to add into xml this part of code

```
<block class="Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="requirejs-config"/>
```

in situation of collision to read *.js vs *.min.js dependencies.